# How to examine `elf` file by hexdump?

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, elf, hexdump

I'm learning `elf` file layout, so I'm reading [Executable_and_Linkable_Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

In the beginning, I used `readelf -a` to exmine `elf(.o file)`, but it provided is not my want, so I used `hexdump -C` to exmined it binaries form.

I used `as -Og -g ... -o ...`, `ld ... -o ...` and `hexdump -C ...` to examine elf file, below is my code.

```
.section .data
iary:
    .int 1, 2
lary:
    .long 3, 4

.section .text
.globl  _start

_start:
    movq $0, %rdi
    leaq iary(, %rdi, 4), %rbx
    movl iary(, %rdi, 4), %ecx

    movq $1, %rdi
    leaq iary(, %rdi, 4), %rbx
    movl iary(, %rdi, 4), %ecx

    #===============================
    
    movq $0, %rdi
    leaq lary(, %rdi, 4), %rbx
    movl lary(, %rdi, 4), %ecx

    movq $1, %rdi
    leaq lary(, %rdi, 4), %rbx
    movl lary(, %rdi, 4), %ecx

    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

I'm looking for `program header, section header`, .etc. But I'm not sure my search method is correct!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WX6E.png]

Please connect with above picture.
[image]

Comment: I am sorry but I have never worked with elf.

Comment: GNU `objdump` can decode ELF files (`.o` and binaries) and tell you what information is there, and where it is in the file.

Comment: There is also (under Linux) a `readelf` utility

Comment: @DaveM. Yeah, `objdump -x` can display **all headers**, but I guess it maybe analyses binary file then displays something we want. So I try to understand the binary file format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the program header:

First, byte 0x4 is 2, so this is a 64-bit binary.  Then, byte 0x5 is 1, so it is little-endian.

Since it is 64-bit, the offset of the program header is at 0x20 and is a 64-bit value.   The bytes here are `40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` which is the little-endian number 0x40.  So as you circled, the program header starts at offset 0x40 in the file.

The section header offset is at 0x28, and points to 0x22f0, so that's where the section headers begin, as you have circled.  The first one has zeros at offset 0x4 (i.e. 0x22f4 in the file), meaning it is unused, which is why you see zeros in the 0x40 bytes starting at 0x22f0.  The first real section header starts at 0x22f0 + 0x40 = 0x2330.

Offset 0x1000 looks like the start of the program's actual code.  It makes sense that it is aligned to a page boundary (0x1000 = 4096 = size of a page).  You could confirm by decoding the section headers; this region will probably turn out to be part of `.text`.  These bytes look like machine code and you could use a disassembler to decode them.  `48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00` is `mov rdi, 0` if I read correctly.

Offset 0x2000 is probably the start of a data section.  The first part looks like an array of 32-bit integers `{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4}`.  Later on we have what is possibly a section of debug info.

Perhaps this will help get you started.

Comment: How do you make sure `offset 0x2000` is data section? And `0x22f0` offsets `0x08`(i.e.  `0x22f8`) followed by 8 byes is zero, which can't correspond to [`sh_flags` of the Section header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Section_header).

Comment: @OnlyWick: I am just guessing about 0x2000 being data.  If you want to be sure, then as I said, you should decode the section headers and see which one occupies that part of the file.

Comment: @OnlyWick: As for 0x22f0, the zeros at offset 0x4 (`sh_type`) mark the section table entry as unused.  Therefore the other contents of that entry, such as the `sh_flags` at 0x8, are meaningless and will be ignored.  In this case it is just filled entirely with zeros, and there is no problem that this doesn't represent a valid section header or otherwise conform to the rules for such a header.